# TF2012 End of support

Tags: tfs

Sorry to ask this here, but i did'nt find any suitable answer on the internet, even in the MS site. In fact, even MS recommands to post the question on So ;) ;)

Does anybody knows (or have the official link) when TFS2012 supports will end for the enterprises ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has a [product lifecycle search application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%202012).

Mainstream support for TFS 2012 Update 4 ended in January of this year.

Extended support ends in 2023.